# ActiveMQ Broker inside WSL or docker throws invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: spring, jdbc, activemq-classic

I wrote a simple program to connect to a DB using a spring bean from inside Docker or WSl2. It connects fine.

The moment I add a broker tag to the XML it fails with error.

NOTE : the 'broker' tag, even when added as empty, commenting everything out, causes the same issue.

Below is my program and the bean XML

```java
public class TestDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection1 = null, connection2 = null;

        try (ConfigurableApplicationContext mContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test.xml");) {
            String jdbcClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
            String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz.company.com:1521:abc";
            String user="TEST_DB";
            String password="test";

           
            BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
            ds.setDriverClassName(jdbcClassName);
            ds.setUrl(url);
            ds.setUsername(user);
            ds.setPassword(password);
            connection1 = ds.getConnection();

            BasicDataSource ds2 = (BasicDataSource) mContext.getBean("application-ds");
            connection2 = ds2.getConnection();

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection1!=null) {
                System.out.println("Connected successfully.");
                try {
                    connection1.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (connection2!=null) {
            System.out.println("Connected via bean.");
                try {
                    connection2.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `test.xml`:

```xml
<beans .....>
   <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" persistent="true" brokerName="ABC_MESSAGING_SERVER" advisorySupport="false" useJmx="false">
      <destinationPolicy>
         <policyMap>
            <policyEntries>
               <policyEntry queue="my_account" />
            </policyEntries>
         </policyMap>
      </destinationPolicy>
      <persistenceAdapter>
         <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#application-ds"/>
      </persistenceAdapter>
   </broker>
   <bean id="application-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz.company.com:1521:abc" />
      <property name="username" value="TEST_DB" />
      <property name="password" value="test" />
      <property name="maxActive" value="200" />
      <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

The output, with the  broker part commented is:

and with broker :

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at TestDB.main(TestDB.java:29)  
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:456)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:451)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1040)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:552)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:550)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:501)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1292)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1025)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.

The problem was my Database was version Oracle 12.2.0.1 and my ojdbc jar was ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.
It did not matter when testing on widnows or linux machines.

However using it alongside activemq broker in WSL2 or Docker (virtual envs basically) then it caused 'Invalid username password logon error'.
had to replace the jar with ojdbc8-12.2.0.1 on client side